# Prevent getStaticPaths running for specific locale

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, server-side-rendering

Is it possible that you prevent Next.js `getStaticPaths` for generating static pages for a specific locale?

In my next config:

```
  i18n: {
    locales: ['default', 'en', 'hu', 'de', 'cz', 'eu', 'sl'],
    defaultLocale: 'default',
    localeDetection: true,
  },
```

That's just because we need the locale all the time, and by the default, Next.js does not support it, so we have to use the middleware trick followed by the official Next.js docs: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18419

But now when I want to generate sites, I don't want to generate pages like

- /default/products/id1
- /default/products/id2

How can I prevent Next.js doing this? Because this does not work:
For my faq page where `/help/[maincategory]/[subcategory]/[help]`.

Using `slice` (I will skip the default locale):

```
 locales.slice(1).map((locale) => {
        pages.map((item) => {
          item.data.mainTabList?.[locale]?.map((main, mainidx) => {
            main.subTabList?.map((sub, subidx) => {
              questions.map((help) => {
                help.data.helplist?.[locale]?.map((title) => {
                  const urllink = {
                    maincategory: urlConverter(main.tab),
                    subcategory: urlConverter(sub.tab),
                    help: title.url
                  }
    
                  routes.push(urllink)
                })
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })

  const paths = routes.map((doc) => ({
    params: {
      maincategory: `${doc.maincategory}`,
      subcategory: `${doc.subcategory}`,
      help: doc.help?.toLowerCase(),
    },
  }))
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this, that `/default` pages won't get generated, because that's just a hacky way for my locale prefix, we won't use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to control which locales `getStaticPaths` will generate paths for by returning the desired locales in the `paths` array.

From the [i18n Dynamic Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages) documentation:

> For pages using `getStaticProps` with [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), all locale
> variants of the page desired to be prerendered need to be returned
> from [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths). Along with the `params` object returned for `paths`,
> you can also return a `locale` field specifying which locale you want to
> render.

---

In your case, your `getStaticPaths` function should roughly look like the following.

```js
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
    // Your own logic
    
    // Filter out the `default` locale, and map through the remaining locales
    locales.filter((locale) => locale !== 'default').map((locale) => {
        pages.map((item) => {
            item.data.mainTabList?.[locale]?.map((main, mainidx) => {
                main.subTabList?.map((sub, subidx) => {
                    questions.map((help) => {
                        help.data.helplist?.[locale]?.map((title) => {
                            const urlLink = {
                                maincategory: urlConverter(main.tab),
                                subcategory: urlConverter(sub.tab),
                                help: title.url,
                                locale // Also push current `locale` value to be used in `paths` array
                            }
                            routes.push(urlLink)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })

    const paths = routes.map((doc) => ({
        params: {
            maincategory: `${doc.maincategory}`,
            subcategory: `${doc.subcategory}`,
            help: doc.help?.toLowerCase(),
        },
        locale: doc.locale // Pass `locale` value here
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I did not know about this locale field usecase.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#non-dynamic-getstaticprops-pages) about **getStaticProps**:

> For non-dynamic getStaticProps pages, a version is generated for each
> locale like above. getStaticProps is called with each locale that is
> being rendered.
>
> **If you would like to opt-out of a certain locale from
> being pre-rendered, you can return notFound: true** from getStaticProps
> and this variant of the page will not be generated.

```
export async function getStaticProps(ctx: GetStaticPropsContext) {
  if (ctx.locale === 'none') { // or check "default"
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
    revalidate: 3600,
  }
}
```